# I have a ionic app and I am upgrading targetSDKVersion to 33 in android. But it's asking me to upgrade "ionic-appauth": "^0.5.1" dependency

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, appauth, targetsdkversion

I have a ionic app and I am upgrading targetSDKVersion to 33 in android. But it's asking me to upgrade "ionic-appauth": "^0.5.1" dependency also. Which i can't upgrade as it will need to recode some part of app.

Please help how should i set targetSDKVersion to 33.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You HAVE to upgrade it because the plugin min required android version is 33. Nothing you can do about it.